# What stored in variable when enter nothing in Java as an input?

Tags: java, input, null, java.util.scanner

I need to know what really stored in the variable when user enters nothing as an input for scanner class.

I tried to use Eclipse debugger and it shows "" as the value for the variable .
I also use an if statement to figure out is it null or not and I am sure it is not null.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter an input");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sc1 = sc.nextLine();
    if (sc1 == null) {
        System.out.println(sc1 + " is null");
    }
    System.out.println("The value of input is: "+sc1);
}
```

Comment: Looks like an empty `String` AKA `String x = "";`.  This is not the same thing as `null`.

Comment: Don't hide `}` at the end of lines. It makes your code needlessly difficult to read.

Comment: Yes, using a Scanner to System.in returns "" when only pressing enter

Comment: If you press Enter an empty string. If you press nothing the application blocks, waits patiently, If you stop editing, maybe Ctrl-C on Windows, `sc.hasNextLine()` should return false, and `sc1` become null. Never tested the last two cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`""` is the **empty string**. It is a valid value for `String`s and you need to be aware of it.

If you want to check on it, try this:

```java
if ("".equals(sc1))
```

Comment: Depending on the context, this could throw a NullPonterException - consider the other way around to use a constant to compare a value, e.g., `if ("".equals(sc1))`

Comment: or `if (sc1.isEMpty())`